# How to format dates in JavaScript specifically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I have a date in the following format `2019-01-02T03:04:05` and I would like to convert and display it in the UI like this: 3rd of Jan 2019. I am not quite sure what format is called and how to convert them into the desired format like this: `3rd of Jan 2019`.

Does anybody know how to achieve this? I am using JavaScript and React for handling this logic.

Comment: You [*did a search*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date) and couldn't find *anything* suitable? In over 5,000 date format questions?

Answer (score 3):

For formatting dates - it is easier (and is a best practice as well) to use a library, like moment.js or similar.

```
moment('your date here').format('output format here (read moment.js docs and see an examles)');

moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');  // June 13th 2022, 10:26:03 am
```

For your case:

```
moment('2019-01-02T03:04:05').format('Do [of] MMM YYYY'); // 2nd of Jan 2019
```

you have the `2nd` of Jan, not the `3rd` of Jan.

Comment: This should be a comment. There are many, many answers already about formatting in moment.js (and pretty much every date library there is or has been). Just link to an existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can format using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) library

`const date = "2019-01-02T03:04:05";`

`format(new Date(date), "do 'of' MMM yyyy"); // 2nd of Jan 2019`

Format Options: https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@Sergej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72599090/9547698).

> For formatting dates - it is easier (and is a best practice as well) to use a library, like moment.js or similar.

But if you would like to create your own functions, I think you could use this.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    const d = new Date(date);
    const day = d.getDate();
    const month = d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
    const year = d.getFullYear();
    return `${ordinal(day)} of ${month} ${year}`;
}

function ordinal(day) {
    const suffixes = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];
    const mod100 = day % 100;
    const suffix = (mod100 >= 11 && mod100 <= 13) ? 'th' : suffixes[(day % 10 < 4) ? (day % 10) : 0];
    return `${day}${suffix}`;
}

console.log(formatDate("2019-01-02T03:04:05")) //Output: '2nd of Jan 2019'
```

Comment: `%` is a [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder), it is not a strictly modulus operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Day.js](https://day.js.org/) ==> Fast 2kB alternative to Moment.js with the same modern API

- For format check section [format](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) and [advanced format plugins](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/advanced-format)

Code:

```js
const dates = [
  '2019-01-01T03:04:05',
  '2019-01-02T03:04:05',
  '2019-01-03T03:04:05',
  '2019-01-04T03:04:05',
  '2019-01-05T03:04:05',
  '2019-01-30T03:04:05',
  '2019-01-31T03:04:05'
]
const datesFormated = dates.map(d => dayjs(d).format('Do [of] MMM YYYY'))

console.log(datesFormated)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.3/dayjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-Ot7ArUEhJDU0cwoBNNnWe487kjL5wAOsIYig8llY/l0P2TUFwgsAHVmrZMHsT8NGo+HwkjTJsNErS6QqIkBxDw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.3/plugin/advancedFormat.min.js" integrity="sha512-MGC6Za7V8BU0nL3GVjgssHGIZkIMM6A+tcnxqwkdDASdOnyHwmCwyoVfxSYDxiznl4DDYeZP0Jn0p5MW+r4Rnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_advancedFormat)</script>
```